# Azure deployment slot with autodeploy does not substitute connections strings

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, staging, azure-deployment

I have an MVC 5 website for which I have a production website on Azure. I added a staging website as a deployment slot on this website. And I configured deployment from source control when I push from git.

In the beginning everything worked nicely. But now the database connection string is not replaced in the web.config file.

I have the connections string in Configure.

What can I do to Azure to replace the connection strings? Or how can I debug this?

Comment: Does the deployment work correctly (meaning the configuration gets swapped out when you publish directly from Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to Azure Preview Portal. Under Application Settings, there is an option to set the setting as a "slot setting". I checked it. And the problem disappeared.

[image: Application Settings]

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is to remote debug your Azure Web Site with Visual Studio, as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx.
Hope it helps,
Marius

Comment: My application works perfectly. It just doesn't work with the correct database. And that's because the db connection is not replaced during deployment. So I don't see how I could use remote debugging for this. Is it possible to debug the deployment with remote debugging?